# Python queue module difficulty

Tags: python, queue

I'm an experienced programmer, but completely new to Python.
I've resolved most difficulties, but I can't get the queue module to work.
Any help gratefully received. Python 3.2.

Reduced to its basic minimum, here's the issue:

```
>>>import queue
>>>q = queue.Queue
>>>q.qsize()
Traceback:
...
   q.qsize()
...
TypeError: qsize() takes 1 argument exactly (0 given)
```

### Documentation...

7.8.1. Queue Objects

Queue objects (Queue, LifoQueue, or PriorityQueue) provide the public methods described below.

Queue.qsize()

---

OK - what argument.... ?

Answer (score 5):

You're not initializing an instance, you're just reassigning the class name to `q`. The "argument" that it's talking about is `self`, the **explicit** self-reference that all Python methods need. In other words, it's saying that you're trying to call an instance method with no instance.

```
>>> q = queue.Queue()
>>> q.qsize()
```

If you've never seen a Python method definition, it looks something like this:

```
class Queue(object):
    # Note the explicit 'self' argument
    def qsize(self):
        # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are simply renaming `queue.Queue` and not instantiating an object.

Try this

```
q = queue.Queue()
print q.qsize()
```